# Convert RGB pdf to CMYK preserve pdf

Tags: ghostscript

I am using ghostscript 9.25 windows.

I am trying to convert RGB pdf to CMYK preserve pdf using following command:

`gswin32c.exe 
-dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOCACHE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceCMYK -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -sOutputFile=out.pdf input.pdf`

input.pdf file here

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8jfnov526nhb9m9/blank.pdf?dl=0

output.pdf file here

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ftrmm32mmixaxqh/out.pdf?dl=0

but my output becomes light compared adobe output, expected result is it should be dark when i do in adobe CMYK preserve option, i am getting little dark compared to ghostscript output. Am I doing anything wrong?
Should I use any icc profile?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You say you are using ImageMagick, yet you give a Ghostscript command line....

I presume that when you say CMYL you mean CMYK.

There is nothing immediately obviously wrong with your command line, but you have given no example file, nor any reason why you expect the result to be 'dark'.

If you want to control the conversion then you will need to supply at least one and possibly up to 4 ICC profiles. You will certainly need a CIE->CMYK Output profile, and you might like to supply ICC profiles for Gray->CIE, RGB->CIE and CMYK->CIE as well, in order to override the default ones Ghostscript is using.

[EDIT]

The problem is nothing to do with colour conversion. Your original file contains nothing except a very large image, which is compressed with the Flate filter (lossless). It looks like this:

[image: Original PDF zoomed to max in Acrobat]

You've turned off auto filtering, but you haven't told Ghostscript which compression filter to use for images, so it sticks with the default, which is JPEG (DCT). The image now looks like this:

[image: Output file, zoomed to max in Acrobat]

For the nature of your original image, JPEG (lossy) compression is an outstandingly bad choice. The output image compresses less well, and it loses fidelity. You should change to using Flate compression instead of JPEG for images of this kind.

By the way, the image in your original PDF file was defined in CMYK space already.

Comment: Kens Question updated with input and out pdf file.Can you explain more about this . also how can i do via ghostscript using ICC profiles(What are the suitable ICC profiles)

Comment: Kens: I have used the below updated command. gswin32.exe -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOCACHE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceCMYK -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -sCompression=Flate -sOutputFile=out.pdf blank.pdf                                                   Attached output pdf file.[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0dw6b12tf8k49xo/out-Flate.pdf?dl=0)                                                                                                         Is it correct methods? Thanks.

Comment: No, you still haven't set the ColorImageFilter, so I imagine you are still getting a JPEG image out.

Comment: gswin32.exe -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOCACHE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceCMYK -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -ColorImageFilter=FlateEncode -sCompression=Flate -sOutputFile=outt.pdf blank.pdf                                            Does above gs command correct? Thanks

Comment: Kens: attached output pdf file after applied ColorImageFilter                             [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fp2ph0rpee8czkm/out-FlateNode.pdf?dl=0)   Check and update me.

Comment: Kens: Can you help me?. Any feedback on my updated output pdf file.

Comment: If you zoom in with Acrobat (or any other PDF viewer) you can see the JPEG artefacts, so you've done something wrong, its still using DCT compression.

Comment: Kens: Can you correct my ghost script command? my intention is convert RGB pdf to CMYK preserver pdf using ghostscript or somethng like pcl or pjl commands, its should be similar to manual output using Adobe acrobat. Thanks.

Comment: You need to add -sColorImageFilter=/Flate. Note that your original file was **already** in CMYK space anyway.

Comment: gswin32.exe -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOCACHE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceCMYK -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -sColorImageFilter=/Flate -sCompression=Flate -sOutputFile=Flate.pdf blank.pdf. Here is the output file [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/au6hiw5iizfbq2q/Flate.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: And your point is ? Zooming in to the rendering you can see the image no longer has DCT artefacts in it. Presumably you are now happy.